# How to capture a group from a absolute fill path without any slash in it using JavaScript

Tags: regex

Here is a sample file path,

`/Users/X/Q/Q-doc/src/templates/demos.js`

The part I would love to capture is `demos`.

Here is another example,

`/Users/X/Q/Q-doc/src/templates/demos1.js`

The target I want is `demos1`.

I tried to use `/\/(.*).js/` to capture the filename but seems it will also capture all the things in between.

Comment: what is your programing language? with \/([^\/]+).js pattern, you can get your expect from group1, instead of the fully group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([^\/]*?)\.js$
```

This will grab everything that is not a forward slash, so long as it's followed by `.js`, from the end of the string.

See it [here](https://regex101.com/r/f5ALq2/1)

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is doing what it should, however your approach needs a fix you can use this approach instead:

```
(\w+)\.js
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vE4rdZ/1)**

Update: in case you need a match for samples like **[Kyle Fairns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5114911/kyle-fairns)** mentioned in his comment you can use

```
.*\/(.*?)\.js
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vE4rdZ/2)**

Comment: yeah, I should think about this. Only grab chars before `.js`. Thank you

Comment: File names, such as `hello-world.js` will not be recognised - will just grab `world.js`

Comment: @KyleFairns thanks for the comment. Updated the answer with that